# Removing ending alpha characters from string in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have one requirement related to XSLT.

i want to remove ending alphabets in my final output string.
here is the example:
Input string:0123467AAA
Output :0123467

i.e no ending alphbets.

i m new to xslt creation,any suggestion is very helpful to me.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0+?  It's trivial in 2.0 or later using regular expressions but quite fiddly in 1.0.  Can you edit the question to show any code you've attempted so far?

Comment: Hi Lan,its 1.0,i didn't tried any code till now,because i dint get any idea related tht

Comment: For the example you've given it would be sufficient to remove _all_ alphabetical characters from the input string, which is a simple application of [the `translate` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate).  Is that sufficient or do you have cases where there are non-trailing alphabetical characters you need to preserve?

Comment: Hi lan,Thanks for ur reply,but how translate function replace alpha from simply sting?wheather we will give like this?translate('$value','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')" ,we placed as a empty?

Comment: That's the idea - `translate(someString, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')` will give you the input string with all A-Z characters removed.

Comment: but lan it removed all alphabets,but i want to remove only ending alphabets,EX:Input string:"abc12345as", so now i want to remove only ending alphabet..i.e abc12345

Comment: OK, so the answer to my question in the third comment is "no".  The example in the question has no alphabetic characters anywhere other than the end, which is why I was asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT 1.0 your only real option for this is to write a recursive template. Write a named template that takes the string as a parameter. Test whether the last character is a letter. (You can find the last character by using substring($s, string-length($s)-1, 1), and you can test whether it is a letter by testing translate($s, 'ABCD..XYZ', '') = ''). If the last character is a letter make a recursive call to your template passing the whole string minus the last character as the value of the parameter (again, by using substring()). Otherwise, return the string. Make sure that your recursion terminates if the string is zero length.

Comment: "*You can find the last character by using substring($s, string-length($s)-1, 1)*" No, that will find the character **before** the last one. To find the last character, use simply: `substring($s, string-length($s))`.